# The role of using Fragments in speed of apps?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My question is about using `Fragments` in our projects is it true that using `Fragments` will reduce speed in our projects ?

Does it affect the speed ?

If yes , how this defect can be fixed ?

If there is some likes about that please share .

This question is because I used 7 `Fragments` in my App but it work slow . Is it caused by the `Fragments` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it true that using Fragments will reduce speed in our projects ?

Not really.

> Does it affect the speed ?

Not really.

> how this defect can be fixed ?

Write better fragments. Use available profiling tools, like Traceview, to determine where problems lie.

> This question is because I used 7 Fragments in my App but it work slow . Is it caused by the Fragments ?

Use available profiling tools, like Traceview, to determine where problems lie, rather than guessing.